# javascript var being overwritten while waiting for jquery to finish animating

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, scope

I have the following code:

```
myObject = function(id){
    var self = this;
    var id = id;

    self.printId = function(){
        console.log(id)
    }
}

var index = 1;

function createObj(){
    myobj = new myObject(index);
    index++;

    jquery.animate({...},5000,function(){
        myobj.printId();
    });
} 

createObj();
createObj();
```

The output is:

```
2
2
```

I expected:

```
1
2
```

Obviously my original myobj is being overwritten when the second createObj() is called. How do I ensure that my myobj is not overwritten while waiting for the animation to finish?

Comment: `myobj` is global. you should make it not global.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to put the *var* keyword at the time to declare your new object.

its a scope issue.

```
function createObj(){
    var myobj = new myObject(index);
    index++;

   jquery.animate({...},5000,function(){
       myobj.printId();
   });
 }
```